# Cannot launch Strider in my local browser when hosted in AWS

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After much pain, I have finally managed to get the [prerequisites for Strider](https://github.com/Strider-CD/strider) installed; nodejs, git, mongodb and node-gyp. I have checked and they all appear to be functioning correctly.

Following [these instructions](https://fullstackforger.com/environment-setup/strider-ci-on-aws-ec2/part-1-strider-setup), I found that pm2 was a nice way to stop and start services, so I am going with that. Again everything appears ok, and it makes lovely noises at me to indicate that stuff is chugging along.

HOWEVER,

I cannot navigate in my local browser. The URL I am using is `ec2-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, with variations of adding `http://` and port 3000 on the end; as well, of course, as modifying the environment to reflect this.

I have created a custom security group for Strider to allow traffic on port 3000 in AWS, the Strider port. However, the browser and Charles still complain that the DNS cannot be resolved. PINGing the domain name yields an `Unknown host`; I can't believe that these sorts of domains need time to propagate do they?

What to do?

== EDIT ==

The Strider rule I have setup looks like this:

[image: here is the rule...]
[image: but this is what appears!]

Comment: can you paste your Security group rules?

Comment: Ok I've added my Strider rule above. It's the only change I've made to the default rules.

Comment: Ok I've adde a screenshot!

Comment: open up port 80 in security group and then try that URL because as per the instruction document you are forwarding port 80 to 3000

Comment: Do you mean simply to navigate to port 80 in the browser, because I have tried that too. What do you mean?

Comment: Add rule to your security group by clicking EDIT in above screenshot http Tcp 80 0.0.0.0/0 and then click save and then check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118834/discussion-between-serlingpa-and-error2007s).

Comment: Looking at the two screenshots you posted, it doesn't look like the security group with port 3000 open is the SG assigned to the EC2 instance. It looks like group assigned to the EC2 instance only has port 22 open.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Mark, I was in the middle of a multitude of reconfiguration options to try and get it working. I have since reset the port to 3000 to see if I can get Apache serving on port 80 but that might just be a red herring....